# How to delete data in text file in Java based on two variables searched?

Tags: java, netbeans, console, console-application, file-handling

So I have this book.txt file containing

```
111 Java Josh Javaaaaaaaaa J1
112 HTML Alex Html J2
```

I wanted to delete one of the file based on the ID or Name with the following code:

```
  public void DeleteBook()
    {
        try
        {
            String bidToDelete;
            System.out.println("Enter Book Name or Book ID to Delete:");
            bidToDelete = sc.next();
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\LMSConsole\\book.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            File TempFile = new File("temp.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(TempFile);
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] wordsinline = line.split(" ");
                if(wordsinline[0]||wordsinline[1].equals(bidToDelete))
                {


                   f.delete();
                   pw.write(line);
                   TempFile.renameTo(f);
                   if(TempFile.renameTo(f))
                       System.out.println("Book has been deleted.");
                   else
                       System.out.println("Cannot delete file.");
                }
                else
                {
                    pw.println(line);
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            br.close();
            pw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

The flow is to separate the searched file while the rest is moved to the temporary txt file. Once the original file deleted, the temp txt is renamed as the previous original txt file.

It keeps generating error. Any advice? I'm a newbie in this file handling thing. Thanks!

Comment: What error does it keep generating.  Just plain  "error" covers a lot of ground!

Comment: Now the error is gone. But I can't delete the txt file, its just rewriting the same thing to temp.txt

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to delete the original file while you're still in the middle of reading it, as well as renaming the tmp file while you're still in the middle of writing it.

Read the book file **all the way through**, writing out to the tmp file  whatever lines you want to keep.  Then close your reader and writer, delete the book file and rename the tmp file.